# Install failed using Wubi under Windows 8

Tags: wubi, windows-8, system-installation

I just ran the wubi installer under windows 8.

After reboot, I got the dual boot option. Windows is still working, but Ubuntu only makes the computer restart.

I had no errors during the installation.

Any idea ? Ty

Comment: what version of ubuntu?

Comment: default : Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: With Wubi, you can install and uninstall Ubuntu easily and safely. For **12.04 LTS only**.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi is not compatible with computers that come with pre-installed Windows8 (see the warning on the download page: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer )

To install Ubuntu alongside Windows8, see the [UEFI community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) and [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported).

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable the secure boot in the bios

Comment: done that, still having the same error.

Comment: Error after chosing the ubuntu system boot is "windows is unable to load, missing files" code : 0x000007B file : \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr

Comment: disable uefi and select legacy boot if you have that option in your bios

Comment: yep just as lovinbuntu said wubi is incompatible. Try installing ubuntu on a separate partition